# Invalid usage of aggregate function Mean() and Type: String

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code is

```
DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
object o2 = dtAll.Compute("MIN(Price)", string.Empty);
object o1 = dtAll.Compute("AVG(Price)",string.Empty);
```

Min returns minimum.. thats work fine. but avg generates error

"Invalid usage of aggregate function Mean() and Type: String."

Datatype of Price Column in sql server is decimal.

Comment: That's not a complete code sample, what's dtAll?

Comment: dtAll is datatable. and i want to find min and avg from resultset.

Comment: please give me solution if you know..

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your issue is the data in the `Price` column. My hunch is that the column is storing the `Price` as text; therefore, when you call `Min(Price)` works perfectly fine because `MIN` is defined for `strings` but when you cal `AVG` doesn't like it because it doesn't know how to calculate the average of a bunch of strings.

In conclusion, make sure that the data type of the `Price` column is a number and your code should work fine as there's no problem with it.

**EDIT**

Demonstrating my point:

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("Price");
t.Columns["Price"].DataType=typeof(string);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DataRow r = t.NewRow();
    r.ItemArray=new object[]{i};
    t.Rows.Add(r);
}

object min = t.Compute("MIN(Price)",string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine("Min: " +min); //PRINTS Min: 0
try
{
    object avg = t.Compute("AVG(Price)", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine("AVG: "+avg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Prints:

> Min: 0
>
> Invalid usage of aggregate function Mean() and Type: String.

Forcing the data type to be int as so:

```
t.Columns["Price"].DataType=typeof(int);
```

Now prints:

> Min: 0
>
> AVG: 4

Comment: I got result in min as well as avg

Comment: Yes, IT IS like that. See my updated answer. The fact that you run the query in the backed and it works doesn't mean that loading the values in the data table must also work. It depends on how you load the data.